# Trying to Order By using Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add 'order by' functionality to my angular app.

I have been trying:

```
<div *ngFor = "let movie of webService.movie_list | async | orderBy:'Year'">
```

And I have been getting this error in the browser:
The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are [No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) in Angular 2.x+ by default due to possible performance impacts. From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe):

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists.
>   Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy.
>   There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they
>   perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification. Both filter and
>   orderBy require parameters that reference object properties. Earlier
>   in this page, you learned that such pipes must be impure and that
>   Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change-detection cycle.
>
> Filtering and especially sorting are expensive operations. The user
>   experience can degrade severely for even moderate-sized lists when
>   Angular calls these pipe methods many times per second. filter and
>   orderBy have often been abused in AngularJS apps, leading to
>   complaints that Angular itself is slow. That charge is fair in the
>   indirect sense that AngularJS prepared this performance trap by
>   offering filter and orderBy in the first place.

Instead just use RxJS in combination with [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort/order your data in the component:

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  movies$: Observable<Movie[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    // Create observable of fake data for demo purposes
    // Use rxjs/operators map to sort the data in ascending order
    this.movies$ = of(data).pipe(
      // You can even extract this operation to a separate function to re-use
      map(movies => movies.sort((a, b) => a.Year - b.Year))
    );
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let movie of movies$ | async">{{movie | json}}</li>
</ul>
```

Just apply the RxJS map operator to sort the data in the direction you need wherever/whenever you have observable stream data come into your component.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1q5thj) in action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your `pipe` in module and declare it in `NgModule` declarations

```
import { OrderByPipe } from './order-by.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [  OrderByPipe ]

})
```

Comment: you can take reference from https://stackblitz.com/edit/order-by-pipe-qwrygp